# Mechanize: list all possible control values

Tags: python, mechanize

Say I have a form like this:

```
<td>
    <select name="text1" class="long" >
     <option value="">-- unknown --</option>
     <option value="1">test1</option>
     <option value="2">test2</option>
     <option value="3">test3</option>
     <option value="4">test4</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Is there a way to get all possible option values, in this case: '','1','2','3','4' using mechanize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need actual html form though:

```
html = '''
<form>
<td>
    <select name="text1" class="long" >
     <option value="">-- unknown --</option>
     <option value="1">test1</option>
     <option value="2">test2</option>
     <option value="3">test3</option>
     <option value="4">test4</option>
    </select>
</td>
</form>
'''
forms = mechanize.ParseString(html, 'fake')
form = forms[1] # 0th is kind of default one here

control = form.controls[0] # the select
print [item.attrs['value'] for item in control.items]

Out: ['', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

upd. made the code prettier